# How can I repeatedly output from a tkinter slider/scale so I can send a constant stream of numbers to another device via serial?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

Essentially what I would like to do is send (over serial) a value of a tkinter scale approximately every 50ms (or as frequently as I can). I would like to send this data even when the slider is stationary. This is for a project I am doing which would include controlling a quadcopter via a raspberry pi.

I am familiar with the 'get()' function and with 'command =' function however I am not sure how to utilise these allowing them to output repeated values.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import serial

def outputValue(value):
    print(value)
    ser.write(value.encode())

def background(window, color):
    window.configure(bg = color)
    scale = tk.Scale(window, from_= 0, to= 20, command = outputValue)
    scale.pack()

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Drone Control")
background(window, "black")
window.mainloop()
```

This outputs a value once when the slider is moved so you never get repeated numbers unless you move the slider away and back to a position.

The perfect output would be one where a value is outputed every 'x'ms.

Comment: I would track your scale in a variable and then use another function managed by an `after()` loop to monitor that variable and constantly send data.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example @Mike-SMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test with serial but the below example should be a clear enough example to get you going.

We can use after to constantly send data to serial and then we can use your scaler to updated a variable that is then sent to serial.

```
import tkinter as tk
# import serial

tracked_var = 0


def outputValue():
    print(tracked_var)
    #ser.write(value.encode())
    window.after(500, outputValue)


def update_tracked_variable(value):
    global tracked_var
    tracked_var = value


def background(color):
    window.configure(bg=color)
    scale = tk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=20, command=update_tracked_variable)
    scale.pack()


#ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Drone Control")
background("black")
outputValue()
window.mainloop()
```